# Blogger data:post.url doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, html, blogger

I'm trying to build my own social sharing links on blogger
but the problem is that **data:post.url** doesn't retrieve the URL of the current post, it seems like it doesn't work at all.

And here's what I'm trying to do in more details:

1) I'd like to create my own sharing links so that my website runs faster than using third party plugins/websites — which usually inject tracking .JS and are not SEO optimized.

2) I'm totally aware that for **data:post.url** to work, I should first add the expression **expr** followed by **href**... for ex: **expr:href**

3) So the final code for a facebook sharing button is like this:

```
<a expr:href='"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + data:post.url' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Facebook Share'><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

When I hover my cursor over Facebook sharing button (or click on it), I get http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u= without the current URL which means that **data:post.url** is not working

Is there a solution or an explanation to this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

After that I posted this question here, I opened an old blog I made a long time ago for testing purposes and started observing the code until I found a similar one, which means that the above is correct.

I did a test, I pasted this one right before the closing **`</body>`** as I used to do and it didn't work. I then tried to paste it in front of the original code and guess what? It worked with no problem!

Well, it's totally normal, thanks to an [article I read](http://thoughtsomething.blogspot.com/2009/01/understanding-blogger-template-2.html) after that, I found out that there are two types of data: Those that can be accessed **anywhere in the theme (Global)** and those that can be accessed **only under their appropriate widget (Local)**.

So **data:post.url** is a local type of data which can be accessed **only under Post widget**!

If you'd like to see a similar code functioning, search for **Blog posts widget** and paste it there under it.

To find **Blog Posts widget**, open the HTML of your theme, then on your keyboard click on **CTRL+F** and type **Blog posts**, you will be directed to **title='Blog posts'**, paste your code anywhere between **`<b:widget title='Blog posts'...`** and **`</b:widget>`**. Save the changes and then visit your website to see how that perfectly works!

For my share buttons, I used another type of data that can be accessed anywhere in the theme: instead of **data:post.url**, I typed **data:blog.url** so that I can put the code right before `</body>`.

If you'd like to see how it works on my blog: [Click Here](https://www.clevious.com)

Answer (score 1):

It should be work. But if not, have you try to remove that double quotes on that facebook link? `'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=+data:post.url'` how it goes?

Comment: I found a solution to this and I'm now writing an answer to it. The problem is not with the double quotes: those are used for 'concatenation' just as in programming languages, but for blogger only.
Thank you.